# How does SSIS determine table structure when importing a table from external source?

Tags: ssis

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2005 (SSMS) I can use the import wizard to create a re-runable SSIS package that will import data from one server to another.  The tables do not exist on the target server, they ony exist on the source server.  When I open the newly created SSIS package in edit mode, I see it has two items on the Control Flow tab - a "Preparation SQL Task", and a "Data Flow Task".  The "Preparation SQL Task" is created with a SQL statement (DDL) creating the table on the target system.

How does the SSIS package determine the correct SQL Statement (DDL) to create the new table?  I have a dynamic source and need to modify the SSIS package to dynamically determine the DDL when creating the new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to create script transformation that will handle dynamic source changes and correct DDL (try to pass it like variable to "Preparation SQL Task")